Getting reference level counts from glm output
I need counts of all levels used in a GLM, including the reference levels. Here is code I am using with an example dataset:
library(tidyverse)
library(writexl)
library(broom)
data(Affairs, package="AER")
Affairs$ynaffair[Affairs$affairs >  0] <- 1
Affairs$ynaffair[Affairs$affairs == 0] <- 0

Affairs <- Affairs %>% 
  mutate_at(c("affairs", "religiousness", "occupation", "rating", "ynaffair"), as.factor)

Affairs$religiousness <- relevel(Affairs$religiousness, ref="1")
Affairs$rating <- relevel(Affairs$rating, ref="1")
Affairs$gender <- relevel(Affairs$gender, ref="female")

example_model <- glm(ynaffair~gender + age + yearsmarried + children + religiousness + education + occupation + rating,
               family = binomial,
             data = Affairs)

n <- colSums(model.matrix(example_model)) ##Suggestion from another post
n_tidy <- tidy(n) %>% 
  rename("Covariate" = 'names') %>% 
  rename("n" = 'x')

output_ex <- tidy(example_model) %>% 
  select(-c(statistic, std.error)) %>% 
  mutate(OR = exp(estimate)) %>% 
  rename("Covariate" = 'term') %>% 
  left_join(n_tidy, by = "Covariate")  %>% 
  select(Covariate, n, OR, p.value) 

write_xlsx(output_ex, "output_ex.xlsx")

This is what I currently get:

This is what I would like:

Another post suggested using  colSums(model.matrix(example_model)), which gets me some of the counts I need, but not all of them.
Any advice or suggestions for a simpler way would be greatly appreciated.

It would be best if you can post your observed and intended output in a text format rather than as images ...

This is a little clunky but seems to do what you want (after you join it with your model outputs) — but I question whether the sum of the values of continuous predictors (which is what this gives you) is really what you want for n ... ?
fn <- function(nm, x) {
   if (is.factor(x)) {
      tt <- table(x)
      return(tibble(var=paste0(nm, names(tt)), n = c(tt)))
   }
   tibble(var=nm, n = sum(x))
}

## take all variables in formula *after dropping LHS*
vars <- all.vars(formula(example_model)[-2])
af2 <- Affairs |> select(any_of(vars))
map2(names(af2), af, fn) |> bind_rows()

  var                 n
   <chr>           <dbl>
 1 genderfemale     315 
 2 gendermale       286 
 3 age            19525 
 4 yearsmarried    4915.
 5 childrenno       171 
 6 childrenyes      430 
 7 religiousness1    48 
 8 religiousness2   164 
 9 religiousness3   129 
10 religiousness4   190 
# ℹ 14 more rows


Here's a slightly more elegant way of enumerating the counts by level for factor variables only in a model (if you want the variable name and level collapsed into a single variable as in your output you can use mutate() + paste0() ...)
xlev <- example_model$xlevels
cfun <- \(nm) { count(Affairs, !!sym(nm)) |>
                   setNames(c("level", "n")) |>
                    mutate(var = nm, .before = 1)
}
map_dfr(names(xlev), cfun)

             var  level   n
1         gender female 315
2         gender   male 286
3       children     no 171
4       children    yes 430
5  religiousness      1  48
6  religiousness      2 164
7  religiousness      3 129
8  religiousness      4 190
9  religiousness      5  70
10    occupation      1 113
11    occupation      2  13
12    occupation      3  47
13    occupation      4  68
14    occupation      5 204
15    occupation      6 143
16    occupation      7  13
17        rating      1  16
18        rating      2  66
19        rating      3  93
20        rating      4 194
21        rating      5 232


It is a bit clunky. If you have any suggestions about how to get the output I need in a simpler or more reliable way I would be open to them.

Also, thank you for pointing out my mistake with the continuous predictors. Is there a way to extract the count for all levels from the glm?

I've just modified it to pick up the name of the response variable automatically.  If you write a wrapper function for this I don't know that you have to care that it's clunky ...

I'm not sure what you mean by "all levels" for continuous predictors. Continuous predictors typically (although not always) have lots of unique values, making them awkward to enumerate.  You could use table(ggplot2::cut_interval(...)) to summarize the numbers within different ranges ... (at some point you should look at the Hmisc::describe() function)

PS someone may well have written a function in a package somewhere that does this kind of summary, I just don't know what it is ...
